# Trying to do frequency scaling of 50 MHz signal to 1MHz with below code. "endmodule" error occurs

Tags: verilog, quartus

```
module PWM_Gen(

input clk,             // Clock input
input [7:0]DUTY_CYCLE, // Input Duty Cycle
output PWM_OUT         // Output PWM
);

reg [7:0]counter_out; // 8-bit counter

always @(posedge clk)   
begin
   if (DUTY_CYCLE > counter_out)
   PWM_OUT = 1;
   else
   PWM_OUT = 0;
end

counter counter_inst (  
    .clk(clk),
    .counter_out(counter_out)
)

endmodule
```

error is -

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at PWM_Gen.v(51) near text:
> "endmodule";  expecting ";".

Comment: For the compile issue --> Please declare counter_out as wire. Use wire [7:0] counter_out and add a semicolon after in the closing bracket of the counter_inst i.e. 
/*Previous code*/
.counter_out(counter_out)
) ; //Here add semicolon

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. You need a `;` after the `counter_inst` instantiation:

```
counter counter_inst (   
    .clk(clk),
    .counter_out(counter_out)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be added after the `counter_inst` instantiation, means `;` after the `)`.